# Provider vs ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, flutter, flutter-provider

Learning more about the `Provider` and `ChangeNotifier` architecture, I find it really similar to the old good MVVM architecture, where a `Widget` is the View and gets notified for changes by the `ViewModel`, which is the `ChangeNotifier`, linked by a `Consumer` and a `Provider`.

Why isn't this called MVVM for Flutter then? Are there any actual differences between those two architectures?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`provider` is by no mean an architecture. It's an ingredient.

There's absolutely nothing forcing you to use `ChangeNotifier` when using `Provider`.

You can use it in combination with other things, including Mobx, BLoC, Redux, ...

Answer (score 8):

Provider is not a `State-Management` library, it's `Dependency-Injection`.

With Provider you can implement almost any type of state-management solution and it makes things much easier for you.

You may heard of `BLoC`, in Flutter it's suggested architecture and people nowadays usually prefer BLoC(Architecture) with Provider(DI).

BLoC architecture is very similar to MVVM, the difference is BLoC is more responsive/modern, also it's suits Flutter's reactive/functional structure better.
But basically, it's arguably same if you are not big fan of `events-state` mechanism. So yes, your observation is true, we usually use `evolved-MVVM` fundamentally.

Comment: Yeah, I use BLoC, it's similar to Android Jetpack ViewModel, but Consumer/ChangeNotifier reminds me a lot of C# WPF ViewModel